# Validating data based on enum type in springboot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I have an object `Grocery`, I have a field `GroceryType` as an `enum` in the `Grocery` object. I have one more field as list `groceryList`.

I need to add a validation to accept only one `groceryList` when `GroceryType` is `MANGO`
Example:

```
//Grocery object
public class Grocery {    
    private GroceryType groceryType;    
    private List<GroceryList> groceryList;    
}

//GroceryList object
public class GroceryList {    
    private String groceryname;    
    private String quantity;    
}

//AddressType enum    
public enum GroceryType {    
    MANGO, ORANGE    
  }        
}
```

Comment: can `GroceryType` be just `String`,  `groceryname` in `GroceryList` and `groceryType` are different?

Comment: You should clarify your problem.

Comment: @HariHaravelan GroceryType is a enum it can only strjng..groceryname in GroceryList and grocerytype are different

Answer (score 0):

a switch case should do the trick for single element

```
GroceryType expression = groceryList[0]
> switch(expression) {
  case GroceryType.MANGO:
    // your code here
    break;
  case GroceryType.ORANGE:
    // your code here
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

You can also use a loop if you need to clean all the data

```
for(int i=0;i<groceryList.length();i++){
    if(groceryList[i]==GroceryType.MANGO){
          //do stuff
     }
     else if(groceryList[i]==GroceryType.ORANGE){
          //do stuff
}
}
```